# rust: Set configs from env and reuse it during app's lifetime

Tags: rust, api

After writing a basic API with rocket, I'm trying to improve it, but I'm not sure how to follow up. Each time a new request comes in, the code keeps looking for the variable from the environment.

```
// Connect to redis
pub fn connect() -> redis::Connection {

let redis_host_name =
    env::var("REDIS_HOSTNAME").expect("missing environment variable REDIS_HOSTNAME");
let redis_password = env::var("REDIS_PASSWORD").unwrap_or_default();

//if Redis server needs secure connection
let uri_scheme = match env::var("IS_TLS") {
    Ok(_) => "rediss",
    Err(_) => "redis",
};

let redis_conn_url = format!("{}://:{}@{}", uri_scheme, redis_password, redis_host_name);
println!("{}", redis_conn_url);

redis::Client::open(redis_conn_url)
    .expect("Invalid connection URL")
    .get_connection()
    .expect("failed to connect to Redis") }
```

I'm looking for a way to set the redis_conn_url right in the initialization and panic if it is missing, like so

```
 fn rocket() -> _ {
 let redis_conn_url: String = get_redis_url(); // panics if it does not exist
 set_persistent_variable("redis_conn_url", redis_conn_url); 
rocket::build().mount(
    "/",
    routes![routes::root],) }
```

Later I would get it from the config instead of querying env again.
Any direction on this or tips to improve the way I'm thinking about it will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview!
Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Especially here on CodeReview it's important that people that want to improve your code are actually able to run it :)

Comment: Also, sorry that I told you that your question should be on codereview, I think it would have been fine on either pages, I didn't realize that you were having an actual proper question :) Your SO post sounded like you just need feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for your usecase, the [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/) crate would be quite useful.

For example:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::env;

lazy_static! {
    static ref REDIS_HOSTNAME: String =
        env::var("REDIS_HOSTNAME").expect("missing environment variable REDIS_HOSTNAME");
    static ref REDIS_PASSWORD: String = env::var("REDIS_PASSWORD").unwrap_or_default();
}

fn main() {
    println!("Credentials: {:?} - {:?}", *REDIS_HOSTNAME, *REDIS_PASSWORD);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Finomnis, that will save me a lot! 
It didn't quite work out with rocket, but loading the .env to the OS did the trick, previously just having the .env set was enough

Also, just to follow up, thanks for pointing me codereview!